# Mnemonic for remembering how to spell "mnemonic"

Tags: mnemonic

It is ironic that the name of a mental device which is supposed to make our lives easier is itself so hard to spell. Is there a mnemonic for the spelling of *mnemonic*?

Comment: I'll give you the benefit of the doubt, but I do hope you're not just trying to be clever in a question.

Comment: It's easier for me to remember "the way it sounds plus an extra M" than to remember another mnemonic.

Comment: @Robusto - I was reading the answer to a different question to my daughter (aged 13) and asked is she had any good questions, which is how this came up.  I think she genuinely wanted to know an easy to remember way to spell mnemonic.

Comment: I, for one, pronounce both the *m* and the *n* at the beginning of *mnemonic*, but this is **not** standard and is just a quirk of mine. I also like to pronounce the *g* at the beginning of *gnu*, the *p* at the beginning of *ptarmigan*, and other such aberrations.

Comment: @JSBangs O, you're not supposed to pronounce that *g*? Guess I've been doing that wrong too. I blame my native language :P

Comment: "I know to spell Mississippi, just that I don't know when to stop."

Comment: But once you learn THIS mnemonic, what if you use it on the word *pneumonic*?

Comment: I picture Monica from the TV show "Friends" (whom I find quite attractive) with a big M tattooed on her knee.   You know, an M on the knee of Monica = mnemonic.  Hey, whatever works for you!

Comment: @JSBձոգչ, you’re not the only one—I also pronounce ‘mnemonic’ exactly as it’s written. I don’t pronounce the p in ‘ptarmigan’ or ‘pterodactyl’, though, nor the ph (or the second h) in ‘phthisis’ (homophonous, except for the stress pattern, with ‘tie sis [up]’).

Comment: Maturity never encompasses making odd names instantly coherent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure; repeat to yourself ***m**y **n**iece is mnemonic*.

This assumes that the *mn* is the source of difficulty and you don't need a mnemonic for the rest of the word.

Comment: +1. I'm convinced you made this up on the spot, which would be awesome.

Comment: @jprete: I'm glad you think so, since yeah, I did. :)

Answer (score 17):

It might help to associate it to a word which is related etymologically: a**mn**esia.

Answer (score 10):

A collection of mnemonics for mnemonic from the web:

- Memorization's Not Easy; Memory Often Needs Initial Cues
- My Nanny Eats Mostly Old Noodles In Cans
- Memory Needs Every Means Of Naming It Correctly
- Mnemonics Neatly Eliminate Man's Only Nemesis - Insufficient Cerebral Storage
- Many Nuns Enjoy Monks Only Not In Convents

But I think the best is @Peter Taylor's simple [suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11564/mnemonic-for-remembering-how-to-spell-mnemonic/11716#11716) to remember a**mn**esia.

Comment: i think the 2nd and the 5th are pretty good ; )

Comment: I'd find it easier to just remember the letters than try to remember the 4th one.

Comment: @Urbycoz Yeah, that's a good example of a bad mnemonic.

Answer (score 3):

If it were a class of words you're talking about, I'd say a mnemonic would be useful. But as you are referring to a single instance, why create a mnemonic that you will have to remember (and may get wrong) to remember a single word? That adds an unnecessary burden (and abstraction) to the task.

Comment: Mnemonics are just as much about specific instances as for general ones - for example, the use of "Naughty Elephants Squirt Water" to remember the clockwise order of the cardinal compass points.

Comment: @HorusKoi: That's four things, not one thing, and an order. Similarly, "I Don't Play Like My Aunt Lucy" lets you remember the musical modes: (Ionian, Dorian, Phrygian, Lydian, Myxolydian, Aeolian, Locrian) helps you remember seven things. My point is, a contrivance to help you remember a single word's *spelling* is actually forcing you to remember a lot more than just the spelling.

Comment: Good point made, Robusto. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try these to remember how to spell MNEMONICS:

- Men Never Eat Many Oysters Near Ice Cold Swamps
- Many New England Memories Of Nantuckett Ice Cold Shrimp

Comment: Who the hell can remember something like this ?

Comment: @Arjun: I guess (hope) that that was the joke. :-)

Comment: [A]: Men Never Eat Many .. what was it again? [B]: Dude, what are you talking about? [A]: I'm trying to recall the mnemonics for mnemonics .. [B]: D'uh! ;)

Answer (score 1):

**M N** E **M** O **N** I C.

Two M's
Two N's

M always comes before N

Never a P!
Never a U!

Comment: who dragged P and U into this whole mess?

Comment: While we're at it- there's no F'in mnemonic.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, I think some people mistakenly think *mnemonic* is related to *pneumonia*, and come up with creative misspellings based on that.

Answer (score 1):

My niece enjoys mnemonics only never in class.

Comment: But that requires you to remember that mnemonics starts with an m.

Answer (score 1):

> My nanny Eva makes oranges not inch closer.

It's a weird one, but that's how it got stuck in my head!

Answer (score 0):

Angry at his last trickery, Seinfeld said: "Mmmm... Newman!"

A bit more in the scientific side: pneumatics, air brakes on buses, trucks and trains are examples of pneumatic systems.

Answer (score 0):

My 11 year old has just been interviewing people for his English project on spelling strategies and just came up with what I thought was a good mnemonic for mnemonic-

**Men Never Eat Marmalade On Nice Ice Creams**

Answer (score 0):

"mnemonic" is based on ancient Greek mnéme  μνήμη  meaning memory.  I'm no great specialist for old Greek so I'm not sure whether the m was really pronounced and I can't give information about the etymology of the word. I would guess something that is in the mind, memories you have in your head.

Answer (score -2):

Hmmm? How to remember how to spell nemonic? (sic)

Hmmm! Spell phonetically by jogging your memory... mnemonic.