# Pneumonic or Mnemonic?

Tags: is-it-a-word

So my English teacher gave us some work and we had to write down 'pneumonics' for some words. I'm fairly sure it's spelt 'mnemonic.' Who's correct?

Edit: The usage being the "memory" words, for example:

Alliteration

Facts

Opinions

Rhetorical question

Emotive language

Statistics

Triples

Where the mnemonic above would be 'AFOREST'

Comment: Both pneumonic and mnemonic are words... to help you, we need to know what kind of words those were that you had to write down.

Comment: @skymninge edited

Comment: *Mnemonic* is memory. *Pneumonic* is *having to do with pneumonia*.

Comment: So 'pneumonic' isn't a word in that way?

Comment: Have you taken the trouble to look up *pneumonic* in a dictionary? It relates to inflammation of the lungs!

Comment: @Jay this seems to be a common misconception, your teacher is not alone (although he/she should have checked). There was a discussion about it in the comments at MW under the entry [*pneumonic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pneumonic).

Comment: You should have raised your hand and said: "Miss (name), I thought it was spelled M•N•E• monics." The two words  do have similar pronunciations, hopefully this was a one-off error made by your teacher, a slip up which can happen to the best of us. (Although ‘M for memory’ is a pretty easy mnemonic)

Comment: related [Mnemonic for remembering how to spell “mnemonic”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11564/mnemonic-for-remembering-how-to-spell-mnemonic)

Comment: +1 for drawing my attention to a blatant misconception that I would never have guessed existed! Personally I pronounce the two words differently, but I can see how the _eu_/_e_ could be homophones.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That question belongs on Meta... it's a prime example of a self-referecing question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pneumonic) :

> **pneumonic** (not comparable)
>
> > 1. Of, or relating to the lungs; pulmonary.
> > 2. Of, or relating to pneumonia.

It has nothing to do with memory. **You are right** by correcting to [mnemonic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mnemonic).